# Select ID, Count(ID) and Group by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, count, group-by

I have an article table which has id and date (month/year) columns, first of all I would like to count ids and group them by date, then I would like to see which id belongs to which date group in single query like that:

```
id   date   count
-----------------
1    01/2015   2
2    01/2015   2
3    02/2015   1
4    03/2015   4
5    03/2015   4
6    03/2015   4
7    03/2015   4
```

I have 2 queries

```
Select Count(id) 
from article 
group by date
```

and

```
Select id 
from article
```

gives results;

```
count date            id  date
-------------         ----------
2     01/2015         1  01/2015
1     02/2015         2  01/2015 
4     03/2015         3  02/2015
```

I need a single query like

```
select count(id), id, date 
from....
```

which brings id, count, date columns to use in my C# code.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Correlated subquery for the Count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
       date,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY date) AS Count
FROM article
```

[Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64fd9/2)

Answer (score 2):

Can't quite do that in one query, but you could use a CTE to produce a single result set:

```
create table #tt (id int null, dt varchar(8))
insert #tt values
(1,'01/2015'),
(2,'01/2015'),
(3,'02/2015'),
(4,'03/2015'),
(5,'03/2015'),
(6,'03/2015'),
(7,'03/2015')

;with cteCount(d, c) AS
(
    select dt, count(id) from #tt group by dt
)
select id, dt, c
from #tt a
inner join cteCount cc
on a.dt = cc.d

drop table #tt
```

results:

```
id  dt      c
1   01/2015 2
2   01/2015 2
3   02/2015 1
4   03/2015 4
5   03/2015 4
6   03/2015 4
7   03/2015 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if not exists(select * from TEST.sys.objects where type=N'U' and name=N'article')
begin
    create table article(
    [id] int,
    [date] date)
end
```

with this data:

```
insert into article(id,date) values(1,convert(date,'15/01/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(1,convert(date,'15/02/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(2,convert(date,'15/03/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(2,convert(date,'15/01/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(3,convert(date,'15/02/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(4,convert(date,'15/03/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(5,convert(date,'15/01/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(5,convert(date,'15/02/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(1,convert(date,'15/03/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(2,convert(date,'15/01/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(3,convert(date,'15/02/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(4,convert(date,'15/03/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(5,convert(date,'15/01/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(1,convert(date,'15/02/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(2,convert(date,'15/03/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(3,convert(date,'15/01/2015',103));
insert into article(id,date) values(4,convert(date,'15/03/2015',103));

select id,[date], count(id) [count] from article
group by [date],[id]

the result:

id  date    count
1   2015-01-15  1
1   2015-02-15  2
1   2015-03-15  1
2   2015-01-15  2
2   2015-03-15  2
3   2015-01-15  1
3   2015-02-15  2
4   2015-03-15  3
5   2015-01-15  2
5   2015-02-15  1
```

Comment: Try this with his original result set and it will be a little clearer as to why this doesn't work.  Note that your sample data has 17 rows but your query only returns 10.

Answer (score 0):

> It's not clear how you want to generate the id field in result. if you
>   want to generate it manually then use `RANK()` or if you want to get it
>   from the table `id` value then you can use `max()` or `min()`(depends
>   upon on your expected result)

Use `RANK()` [Fiddle Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1701/9)

Try:

```
create table tt (id int null, dt varchar(8),count int)
insert tt values
(1,'01/2015',2),
(2,'01/2015',2),
(3,'02/2015',1),
(4,'03/2015',4),
(5,'03/2015',4),
(6,'03/2015',4),
(7,'03/2015',4)
```

Query:

```
 select count(id) as count,dt,RANK() 
    over(order by count(id)) as id from tt group by dt
```

**EDIT2:**
or you just can use `MAX()` or `MIN()`

like:

```
select count(id) as count,dt,Min(id) as id from tt group by dt
```

or

```
select count(id) as count,dt,MAX(id) as id from tt group by dt
```